# Http3 with Laravel and Forge

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-10, forge, http3

Is it possible to implement Http3 when using Laravel 10 and Forge with nginx?

I have tried it myself but i didnt found anything on the Internet.

Is Http3 even the current standard or is it still http2?

Has anyone experience with this topic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The short answer is yes: latest NGINX mainline supports HTTP/3 provided that you compile it with the latest OpenSSL version, or QuicTLS. But it is recommended to rely on distribution packages, where available.